# EclipseLink not generating joins when using Criteria API

Tags: sql, jpa, eclipselink, criteria-api

I am using EclipseLink to build queries. However I'm concerned about the fact that it's not using JOIN syntax in any query defined with Criteria API.

See the following query:

```
// create criteria builder and create query
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Org> query = cb.createQuery(Org.class);

// define root and joined tables
Root<Relationship> rel = query.from(Relationship.class);
Join<Relationship, Org> theOrg = rel.join(Relationship_.party1);

// finish query
query.where(cb.equal(rel.get(Relationship_.party0Id), filterValue));
query.select(theOrg);
query.orderBy(cb.asc(theOrg.get(Org_.name)));

// return results
...
```

I am expecting something like:

```
SELECT O.FIELD1, O.FIELD2, ... O.FIELDN
FROM RELATIONSHIP R
INNER JOIN ORG O ON R.PARTY1 = O.ID
WHERE R.PARTY0 = <filterValue>
ORDER BY O.NAME ASC
```

However I'm getting this:

```
SELECT t0.ID, ... t0.FIELDN
FROM ORG t0, RELATIONSHIP t1 
WHERE ((t1.PARTY0 = ?) AND (t0.ID = t1.PARTY1)) 
ORDER BY t0.NAME ASC
```

Is there anything missing? or is it just the way it works?

I am using Oracle backend

Thanks!

Comment: A Criteria "join" call should indeed translate to a JOIN in the resultant SQL. Raise a bug on your JPA provider

Comment: the JPA spec does not dictate what SQL gets generated, so as long as the SQL contains the join (it is in the where clause) and the results are as expected, it isn't technically a bug. That said, EclipseLink picks what SQL optimizations to use based on the database platform class being used, and the join type can be specified manually as well. Check your persistence properties and try setting the target-database property to match your database version https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/p_target_database.htm